# Hostage Taker + Inspiring Statuary

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Hostage Taker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHostage%20Taker%5d) reads:

> When Hostage Taker enters the battlefield, exile another target
>   creature or artifact until Hostage Taker leaves the battlefield. You
>   may cast that card for as long as it remains exiled, and you may spend
>   mana as though it were mana of any type to cast that spell.

[Inspiring Statuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInspiring%20Statuary%5d) reads:

> Nonartifact spells you cast have improvise.

Can I pay {X} to summon the Hostage Taker's exiled permanent using Improvise (tap a artifact permanent to pay {1} of its cost) up to {0} cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No, improvise can only help pay for the generic mana costs of spells.

> 702.125a Improvise is a static ability that functions while the spell with improvise is on the stack. “Improvise” means **“For each generic
>   mana in this spell’s total cost, you may tap an untapped artifact you
>   control rather than pay that mana.”**

While Hostage Taker enables you to "spend mana as though it were mana of any type to cast the spell" to pay for the non-generic portion of the mana cost, that does not make it a generic mana cost. The mana in your pool is transmutable, while the mana in the cost retains its mana type. It is a case of all thumbs are fingers but not all fingers are thumbs.

Also from the gatherer entries on Improvise: Improvise can’t pay for White, Blue, Black, Red, Green, or Colorless mana symbols in a spell’s total cost.

Do remember that the statue only gives non-artifacts improvise. This includes ones from zones you would not be able to cast them normally from (Like what is the case from the Hostage Taker.)

Comment: Congrats on reaching 1k! :)

Comment: "Enchantment"? It sounds like you meant to refer to Hostage Taker there (it's a creature).

Answer (score 9):

No.  Hostage Taker says **mana** may be spent as though it were any type.  Improvise does not generate mana, and therefore cannot be used to pay for any mana-type specific parts of the cost.  Improvise may still be used to pay for the generic mana portion of the cost (if any).